# writing an R pkg that builds an executable during installation

Tags: r, makefile, installation, package

I am writing an R package that needs to include an executable file (“mod.exe” in Windows environments or “mod” in Unix environments). One of the R functions in the package makes a call to the system that calls the executable as follows:

system(paste("mod", …))

Since CRAN will not accept packages with binary codeand because I would like the package to be portable to both Window and Unix systems, I would like to be able to just include the C source (“.h” and “.c”) files that can be used to build the executable “mod” in the source package. Ideally, when a user installs the R package, the source files should be compiled (with a C compiler available through Rtools on Windows or through a native C compiler on Unix) to create the executable “mod” during installation. Then, ideally, the executable “mod” would be stored in the binary package so that the aforementioned R function can call “mod” directly. (The .h and .c files have already been written so I do not want to rewrite or modify them.)

I've read http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html, looked through https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html, and tried to find packages on CRAN that have already done something like what I’ve proposed, but haven’t been successful. I I attempted to solve my problem by putting all the C source files for “mod” into a /src directory in the source package along with a working makefile in the hope that this would cause the building of “mod” when the package was built and cause it to be stored somewhere in the binary package so that the R function could call “mod”. However, this did not work and when I try to look into the binary package the only thing I can see that was created is a /libs folder containing /i386 and /x64 folders, which both contain a dynamic linked library (on Windows, “RMCSim.dll”)-- I do not know what to do with this DLL.

If I create a version of the package in which the executable “mod” is placed into a package directory called “exec”, the R function can call the “mod” function. Unfortunately, this solution (1) is not portable to both Windows and Unix environments and (2) leads to a package that cannot be accepted by CRAN.

Please respond if you have any ideas for how to approach this problem or if you know of any examples of packages that do something similar with C source code. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need your package to be available on the CRAN? Is your package going to be useful to other peoples too? I'm asking because you could simply put your package on github, gitlab or any other git repository.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! The person I am writing this package for would really like it available on CRAN, if possible. It will be useful to other scientists in his field. Do you know if this is a difficult task to accomplish? I was hoping there was a relatively easy solution I had just not found yet.

Comment: This can be a bit difficult because the CRAN is a bit "strict" on the packages it accepts because they must meet certain conditions. I suggest you wait for an answer to your question (maybe someone have a better idea of what to do in your case) altough I do think that using Github or GitLab would be simpler for you and probably less work.